# Find a service with Partial name VBS

Tags: vbscript, scripting

We have a service that runs with different names on different machines like

Bomgar-scadsadccd, Bomgarsdscchfn, Bomgarscnkfkdk

So, here we need to write a VB script that will find this service with partial name "Bomgar" 
and check it's status like

1) Not present, then should install from a shared folder like "start \10.216.16.245\Bomgar.exe"
2) Installed but not running, then start the service.
3) Installed and running then quit.

How can we achieve this?

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service where Name='bomgar*'") 
nItems = colRunningServices.Count 

If nItems > 0 Then 
    For Each objItem in colRunningServices 
        If objItem.State = "Stopped" Then 
            objItem.startservice
        ElseIf objItem.State = "Running" Then
            exit
        End If
    Next
Else
    start \\10.18.23.245\Shared\Bomgar.exe
End If
```

Comment: Show us what you have so far and tell us which part specifically you're having trouble with. It sounds like you're asking us to write the whole thing for you, which is likely why you're being downvoted.

Comment: I am completely new to this and this is what i tried.     "strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service
where Name='bomgar*'")
nItems = colRunningServices.Count
 If nItems > 0  Then
For Each objItem in colRunningServices
 If objItem.State = "Stopped" Then objItem.startservice   
            ElseIf objItem.State = "Running" Then exit
               
End If 
 Next 
Else 
        start \\10.18.23.245\Shared\Bomgar.exe
End If

Comment: I added your code to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `like` keyword and `%` wildcards in your WQL statement to find any services containing certain text. For example:

```
Set colRunningServices = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Service where Name like '%bomgar%'")
```

And instead of `start`, you'll need to use something like the `Run` command of the `WshShell` object to launch your EXE:

```
With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    .Run "\\10.18.23.245\Shared\Bomgar.exe"
End With
```

Comment: I have tried this and it is working. If the client is not present it is installing from a shared folder, but when the service is stopped it is not starting it.Used the below.                      For Each objItem in colRunningServices 
       If objItem.State = "Stopped" Then 
       objItem.startservice()
                End If

Comment: How to post the script like you did above?